Inline python script in cmake execute_process fails on windows
I'm working on a project that uses cmake, and it is failing while trying to locate my python interpreter. cmake v3.26 is being run under cmd.exe on Windows 10.
The error message is
CMake Error at <project_path>/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2175 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  <project_path>/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPython.cmake:606 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)

Digging further in, it seems that it is running the following execute_process inside Support.cmake:
 execute_process (COMMAND ${_${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_INTERPRETER_LAUNCHER} "${_${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_EXECUTABLE}" -c
                         "<inline python script>"
                         RESULT_VARIABLE _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_RESULT
                         OUTPUT_VARIABLE _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_LIBPATHS
                         ERROR_QUIET)

The inline python script is line separated with \n, and uses either distutils or sysconfig to print the paths of various python folders, which cmake the expects to parse back into internal variables, however even though _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_RESULT comes out 0 indicating no error, _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_LIBPATHS comes back empty.
I've isolated this problem into a standalone cmake script:
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
set(_PYTHON_PREFIX "Python")
execute_process (COMMAND "<abspath>" -c "import sys\nsys.stdout.write('one')"
                         RESULT_VARIABLE _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_RESULT
                         COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT
                         OUTPUT_VARIABLE _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_LIBPATHS
                         ERROR_VARIABLE _${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_ERR)
cmake_print_variables(_${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_LIBPATHS)
cmake_print_variables(_${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_RESULT)
cmake_print_variables(_${_PYTHON_PREFIX}_ERR)

With <abspath> being an absolute path to the desired python.
Running this with cmake -P test.cmake results in:
Prompt>cmake -P test.cmake
'<abspath>' '-c' 'import sys
sys.stdout.write('one')'
-- _Python_LIBPATHS=""
-- _Python_RESULT="0"
-- _Python_ERR=""

If I change the \n to a ; to make it a one-liner, _Python_LIBPATHS gets correctly set to one.
What can I change to allow cmake to successfully get through this script in FindPython/Support.cmake ?
